# How can I replace all occurrences of a substring using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string, `s = 'sdfjoiweng%@$foo$fsoifjoi'`, and I would like to replace `'foo'` with `'bar'`.

I tried `re.sub(r'\bfoo\b', 'bar', s)` and `re.sub(r'[foo]', 'bar', s)`, but it doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `print re.sub(r'\bfoo\b', 'bar', s)` is correctly giving me `sdfjoiweng%@$bar$fsoifjoi`

Comment: perhaps you are mistakenly expecting `s` to be modified in place?  Strings in Python are immutable. The new modified string will be returned by `re.sub`.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I am a beginner with regex and completely forgot that the string could not be modified in place. I retested my original code, and yes, it does work.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can replace it directly:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'sdfjoiweng%@$foo$fsoifjoi'
>>> print(re.sub('foo','bar',s))
sdfjoiweng%@$bar$fsoifjoi
```

It will also work for more occurrences of `foo` like below:

```
>>> s = 'sdfjoiweng%@$foo$fsoifoojoi'
>>> print(re.sub('foo','bar',s))
sdfjoiweng%@$bar$fsoibarjoi
```

If you want to replace only the 1st occurrence of `foo` and not all the `foo` occurrences in the string then alecxe's answer does exactly that.

Comment: I'm not sure if OP is okay with `foo` being replaced in parts of words, like in your second case.

Comment: Plus, why `re.sub()` then and not `replace()`?

Comment: @alecxe, I totally agree with you that `replace` also could be used instead - as it is considered more readable, but the OP asked specifically for `regex`. As for the first comment the OP should specify if he wants `foo` being replaced in parts of words.

Answer (score 7):

> `re.sub(r'\bfoo\b', 'bar', s)`

Here, the `\b` defines [the word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) - positions between a word character (`\w`) and a non-word character - exactly what you have matching for `foo` inside the `sdfjoiweng%@$foo$fsoifjoi` string. Works for me:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]:  s = 'sdfjoiweng%@$foo$fsoifjoi'

In [3]: re.sub(r'\bfoo\b', 'bar', s)
Out[3]: 'sdfjoiweng%@$bar$fsoifjoi'
```

Comment: My only problem with \b that it doesn't work when spaces are the bounderies around the word. Do you have some solution on it? e.g. `s = 'sdfjoiweng%@$foo foo $fsoifjoi'` won't work

Answer (score 5):

You can use replace function directly instead of using regex.

```
>>> s = 'sdfjoiweng%@$foo$fsoifjoifoo'
>>>
>>> s.replace("foo","bar")
'sdfjoiweng%@$bar$fsoifjoibar'
>>>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

To further add to the above, the code below shows you how to replace multiple words at once! I've used this to replace 165,000 words in 1 step!!

Note \b means no sub string matching..must be a whole word..if you remove it then it will make sub-string match.

```
import re
s = 'thisis a test'
re.sub('\bthis\b|test','',s)
```

This gives:

```
'thisis a '
```

Comment: My only problem with \b that it doesn't work when spaces are the bounderies around the word. So `e.g: re.sub('\bthis\b|test', '', 'thisis this a test')` results in `thisis this a ` Do you have some solution on it?

Comment: I want to get `thisis  a` as a result. So I want to replace the 2nd this in the string.

Comment: More understandable example: `thisis this this a test` to `thisis that that a that`

Comment: Here's what you need ```re.sub('\bthis\b|test| this', '', 'thisis this a test')```  this should give you ```'thisis a '```. if you my answer useful I'll appreciate up-voting my initial response to the post. Thanks :-)

Comment: I intend to upvote you, :) your aproach would be perfect, actually I tried this also, but my problem with it, that it replaces the surrounding spaces as well. So I just want to replace the actual world and leaving all spaces around that as are.

Comment: Maybe some basic search replace will be better, anyway I gave you an up. :) I will wait for a possible answer of you though.

Comment: Oh great thanks :-)...I would have suggested a 2 step approach to fix the problem but seems you found a solution already...can you please post your solution so that I'd learn from it too? :-)

Comment: This is my solution: `re.sub("\bthis\b|test", "Q", re.sub(" this ", " Q ", "thisis this is a test"))` It is a nested van, as I talked about a nested solution, but of course it can be a two liner as well (as I actually did it). The result: `thisis Q is a Q`